# Scale two images proportionally in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have two images in html. I need to scale the images proportionally using jQuery. On scaling two images, resize should be taken place.

Comment: What have YOU done already to solve this? Where is YOUR code?

Answer (score 1):

If with "proportionally" you mean that each of the two images should keep the original aspect ratio (i.e 16:9 or 4:3), setting just the width (or height) of an image, and leaving blank the other dimension, will resize the image proportionally ...

```
$("img").css({width:100px, height:auto});
```

or

```
$("img").css({width:auto, height:75px});
```